# How to correctly resize an element by dragging?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop

I have two divs serving as two panels one to the left and one to the right.

They take 70% and 30% of the area.

I have a separator between them.

When I drag the separator to the left or right, I want that to remain as the position of the separator. i.e., I should be able to dynamically resize the left and right divs by dragging.

Here is the code I have:

http://jsbin.com/witicozi/1/edit

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<body>
  <div style='height: 100px'>
    <div id='left'>...</div>
    <div id='separator'></div>
    <div id='right'>...</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
  #left {
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
  }
  #separator {
    float: left;
    width: 3px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: gray;
    cursor: col-resize;
  }
  #right {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
  }
```

JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector('#separator').addEventListener('drag', function (event) {
  var newX = event.clientX;
  var totalWidth = document.querySelector('#left').offsetWidth;
  document.querySelector('#left').style.width = ((newX / totalWidth) * 100) + '%';
});
```

The problems:

1. The resizing happens, but the separator jumps around randomly. It even falls down many times. I have no idea what's happening.
2. The mouse cursor changes to a hand when the dragging begins. I want it to remain a `col-resize`.
3. It is very hard to drag.

**No JQuery please.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a bit of a different approach: rather than using the drag and drop functionality, I used some coupled mouse down and mouse up listeners. This has better cross-browser compatibility (at least as far as my testing goes) and it has the added benefit of being able to easily control the cursor.

```
var resize = function(event) {
    var newX = event.clientX;
    document.getElementById('left').style.width = (newX / window.innerWidth * 100) + '%';
};
document.getElementById('separator').addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', resize);
  document.body.style.cursor = 'col-resize';
});
document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event) {
  document.removeEventListener('mousemove', resize);
  document.body.style.cursor = '';
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use `console.log(event)`, it shows that `event.clientX` doesn't return exactly what you are looking for. The following JavaScript worked for me in chrome.

```
document.getElementById('separator').addEventListener('drag', function(event) {
    var left = document.getElementById('left');
    var newX = event.offsetX + left.offsetWidth;
    left.style.width = newX + 'px';
});
```

The `event.offsetX` value that it is returning is the location (in px) of the upper left hand corner of the left div. This will give you the same result but using percentages so that when the resize the window the columns adjust:

```
document.getElementById('separator').addEventListener('drag', function(event) {
    var left = document.getElementById('left');
    var newX = event.offsetX + left.offsetWidth;
    left.style.width = (newX / window.innerWidth * 100) + '%';
});
```

Comment: I'm still working on how to get the cursor to stay the same. I haven't had much luck yet.